# Use ExtendedCanvas as Canvas - Android SDK

Tags: java, android, sdk

I have a class:

```
public class ExtendedCanvas extends Canvas {
    . . .
}
```

And i want to use this on ondraw of one view:

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //erroneous example:
    ExtendedCanvas SBT = (ExtendedCanvas) c;
    . . .
}
```

Comment: you cannot do that, what would you want that "extended canvas" for?

Comment: I implemented a code that uses percentage for drawing

Comment: so make a wrapper: `new ExtendedCanvas(canvas)`

Comment: I will try.....

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: yes, it does work - just make `Canvas canvas` field inside and use it in your drawing code

Comment: so, ExtendedCanvas doesn't need to be extended?

Comment: `class ExtendedCanvas { private Canvas canvas; public ExtendedCanvas(Canvas canvas) {this.canvas = canvas;} ... }`

Comment: Doesn't worked, i made exactly this

Comment: It shows a blank screen, on the place of my game

Comment: Ok, i will post all the code